# How to bypass the activation screen iPhone 5s (a1530) without sim?

Tags: iphone

How can i bypass the activation screen of iPhone 5s (a1530) without sim card in india.
The emergency call method is not working.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think he's talking about SIM activation, not iCloud activation.

Comment: Ahhh...ok... :/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to activate it without a SIM card, but one shouldn't be that hard to get ahold of. Even borrowing one from a friend's phone for one minute or just buying a deactivated "dummy" SIM card on eBay will work fine.